# How to send any data to my web page in a query string (Windows phone)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, query-string

I have a windows phone application and I need to send some information from my app to a web page that I have. I need to send some information from my app by querystring to the web page.

Any help / example of how I could do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data in form of key/value to your server, you can simply call a url as if you were downloading a string from a url. Just deliver your parameters in that url.

```
new System.Net.WebClient()
 .DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://yourSite.com/saveValues.php?key1=value1&key2=value2"));
```

If you want to parse a feedback from your server, whether saving was successful or not, you can return this information as text and await the feedback from your server using the `DownloadStringCompleted` event from the webClient. Eighter way is not blocking your thread and the app will continue to run smooth.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use web client like this

`parameter = new StringBuilder();
parameter.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "name_of_your_parameter", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value_to_send));`

`webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = parameter.Length.ToString();
webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(your_url), "POST", parameter.ToString());
webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(your event handler);`

this code will send your query string as POST method.

Comment: Thank you! there is no way to send data by GET method?

Comment: I haven't try to use GET to send data, but please consider using POST method if you want to send credential data.